# Is it possible to determine which Fortran compiler generated a ".mod" file?

Tags: module, compilation, fortran

Say I have a package already installed on my machine and I want to figure out if I need to regenerate the module include files (`.mod`) to make them compatible with the rest of my compilation. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There's certainly no Fortran-standard way of doing this, `.mod` files are not mentioned in the standard (nor are many others for that matter).  Right now the form and contents of `.mod` files are implementation-specific, and scarcely documented.  I guess you can probably poke around in them with an editor and may be able to find out what you want, and I guess your compiler might have an option to insert the compiler information into a `.mod` file.  I guess you can re-create them multiple times while you figure this all out ...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I came across many situation that I felt the need to have this info. As you mentioned, they seem to be dependent on the compiler type and version. Of course, eventually one can recompile everything with a common compiler, but it can be tedious sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem at some point with libraries and module files but no sources. Because it is easier to get the right compiler than to get the source code for recompiling in some cases, or to recompile only few things as mentioned by the OP, I found it useful to get the versioning of gfortran module somewhere on SO. Unfortunately, the information is not easy to find, so there is a need of reverse engineering and anyone is welcome to edit and add more.

I did a little bit of googling and here is the starting point:
For gfortran the module versioning appeared at "gfortran 4.4" according to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54797). It is important to say that the version number is for the module not for the compiler. I guess it changes when the format of the module file changes to account for some new features.

By combining information from [this page](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/sw/gfortran.html), [this pages](https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2015/07/27342.php), [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54797) and the answer from matthieu-verstraete, I came up with this list of correspondence.

```
GCC version    module file version
-----------------------------------
up to 4.3.2    unversioned
4.4            0
4.5.1          4
4.6.3          6
4.7.0pre       8
4.7.1          9
4.8.[1-3]      10
4.9.2          12
5.1.0          14
8.1.0          15 
9              15
10             15
11             15
```

From version `4.8` on, the gfortran team includes a small message in the release notes when the module version changes. The message looks like

> Module files: The version of the module files (.mod) has been incremented

as it can be read from [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News#gfortran_4.8). They do not give the version number, and it seems that when they say incremented, it is incremented by `2`.
The update of the module version in gfortran version 8 incremented by 1, and the [gfortran wiki] [5](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News#GCC8) does not say anything about it as of this writting. Thank you to matthieu-verstraete for digging it up.

Answer (score 7):

If the module is built using gfortran then using strings on the mod file (on Linux) will provide the compiler name and the version number. However, for Intel, the strings command will only show the compiler version number.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The idea seems to be printing the readable characters in the file, as Mark mentioned in the comments. I checked it with `gfortran-4.8.2` and it returned `GFORTRAN module version 10 created from file.f90`. What does 10 refer to? As you mentioned, for intel it returned only a number which is presumably the version... I was trying to find more solid ways, which apparently is not available.

Comment: @Amir The module versioning number is not very clear. For gfortran-4.6.3, it is 6 and for gfortran-4.8.2 it is 10. On the gfortran website at [https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News) it states `Module files: The version of the module files (.mod) has been incremented. Fortran MODULEs compiled by earlier GCC versions have to be recompiled, when they are USEd by files compiled with GCC 4.8, because GCC 4.8 is not able to read .mod file of earlier GCC versions; attempting to do so gives an error message.`

Comment: The method of `strings some_module.mod` does not return a meaningful string for mod files created by gfortran 7.2.0 (while it does for gfortran 4.8) as far as I tried. In fact, the release comments for version 4.9 in  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News says "additionally, module files are now compressed." Is there a way to extract the message like "GFORTRAN module version '10' created from .." from mod files generated by the recent versions of gfortran?

Comment: @norio raises an important point. I tried using strings, and got a bunch of garbage characters. Anyone knows a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 4):

For recent gfortran versions:

1. cp mymodule.mod test.mod.gz
2. gunzip test.mod.gz
3. read file test.mod - the first line will contain the module version, which is an internal counter for gfortran developers. See post above for a list of correspondences. For gfort 8.1.0 we are at version 15.