# Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions in mpif-sizeof.h

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran

I have the following makelist file:

```
BIN_SUFFIX = cpu
OMP_FLAGS = -p
OPT_FLAGS = -ofast
compiler = mpifort
compiler = mpif90


#used in gfortran
MISC_FLAGS = -ffree-line-length-300 #

CFLAGS += $(OPT_FLAGS)
CFLAGS += $(OMP_FLAGS)
CFLAGS += $(MISC_FLAGS)

LFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

COMPILE = ${compiler} -c
LINK = ${compiler}

objects = Main_multiphase.o Main_singlephase.o Module.o Init_multiphase.o Init_singlephase.o Misc.o IO_multiphase.o IO_singlephase.o Kernel_multiphase.o Kernel_singlephase.o Mpi_misc.o Mpi_pdf.o Mpi_pdf_acc.o Boundary_singlephase.o Boundary_singlephase_special_case.o Boundary_multiphase_inlet.o Boundary_multiphase_outlet.o Boundary_multiphase_other.o Boundary_multiphase_special_case.o Monitor.o Phase_gradient.o Monitor_special_case.o
LBM : $(objects)    
    ${LINK} $(LFLAGS) -o MF_LBM.$(BIN_SUFFIX) $(objects) 

Module.o : Module.F90
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Module.F90
Main_multiphase.o : Main_multiphase.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Main_multiphase.F90
Main_singlephase.o : Main_singlephase.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Main_singlephase.F90
Misc.o : Misc.F90 Module.o  
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Misc.F90
Monitor.o : Monitor.F90 Module.o    
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Monitor.F90
Monitor_special_case.o : Monitor_special_case.F90 Module.o  
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Monitor_special_case.F90
Boundary_multiphase_inlet.o : Boundary_multiphase_inlet.F90 Module.o    
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Boundary_multiphase_inlet.F90
Boundary_multiphase_outlet.o : Boundary_multiphase_outlet.F90 Module.o  
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Boundary_multiphase_outlet.F90
Boundary_multiphase_other.o : Boundary_multiphase_other.F90 Module.o    
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Boundary_multiphase_other.F90
Boundary_multiphase_special_case.o : Boundary_multiphase_special_case.F90 Module.o  
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Boundary_multiphase_special_case.F90
Boundary_singlephase.o : Boundary_singlephase.F90 Module.o  
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Boundary_singlephase.F90
Boundary_singlephase_special_case.o : Boundary_singlephase_special_case.F90 Module.o    
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Boundary_singlephase_special_case.F90
Kernel_multiphase.o : Kernel_multiphase.F90 Module.o    
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Kernel_multiphase.F90
Kernel_singlephase.o : Kernel_singlephase.F90 Module.o  
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Kernel_singlephase.F90
Init_multiphase.o : Init_multiphase.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Init_multiphase.F90
Init_singlephase.o : Init_singlephase.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Init_singlephase.F90
IO_multiphase.o : IO_multiphase.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) IO_multiphase.F90
IO_singlephase.o : IO_singlephase.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) IO_singlephase.F90
Phase_gradient.o : Phase_gradient.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Phase_gradient.F90
Mpi_misc.o : Mpi_misc.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Mpi_misc.F90
Mpi_pdf.o : Mpi_pdf.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Mpi_pdf.F90
Mpi_pdf_acc.o : Mpi_pdf_acc.F90 Module.o
    ${COMPILE} $(CFLAGS) Mpi_pdf_acc.F90

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod
    rm MF_LBM.$(BIN_SUFFIX)
```

When I run the following command: `make`, I get the following errors:

```
$ make
mpif90  -c   -ofast -p -ffree-line-length-300   Main_multiphase.F90
Main_multiphase.F90:485:0:

 #endif

Warning: null character(s) ignored
mpif-sizeof.h:66:41:

Error: Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions
mpif-sizeof.h:72:41:

Error: Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions
mpif-sizeof.h:78:41:

Error: Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions
mpif-sizeof.h:84:41:

Error: Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions
mpif-sizeof.h:90:41:

.
.
.

Error: Ambiguous interfaces in generic interface 'mpi_sizeof' for ‘mpi_sizeof_real64_r14’ at (1) and ‘mpi_sizeof_real64_r15’ at (2)
mpif-sizeof.h:2631:39:

mpif-sizeof.h:2638:39:

Error: Ambiguous interfaces in generic interface 'pmpi_sizeof' for ‘pmpi_sizeof_real64_r14’ at (1) and ‘pmpi_sizeof_real64_r15’ at (2)
mpif-sizeof.h:1315:38:

mpif-sizeof.h:1322:38:

Error: Ambiguous interfaces in generic interface 'mpi_sizeof' for ‘mpi_sizeof_real64_r14’ at (1) and ‘mpi_sizeof_real64_r15’ at (2)
mpif-sizeof.h:2631:39:

mpif-sizeof.h:2638:39:

Error: Ambiguous interfaces in generic interface 'pmpi_sizeof' for ‘pmpi_sizeof_real64_r14’ at (1) and ‘pmpi_sizeof_real64_r15’ at (2)
make: *** [makefile:43: Main_multiphase.o] Error 1
```

I have the following version of Fortran installed:

```
$ mpif90 --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is this issue due to the incompatibility of the compiler? My system is running Windows 10 64-bit version and I am using Cygwin.

Openmpi installation in Cygwin

[image]

Comment: The error is about your code, not about the Makefile. Please show the offending code.

Comment: Fortran 2008 extended the possible number of ranks. lease try a more recent compiler version.

Comment: But where is the error in the code? It is not referenced in the error log. However, it makes mention of `mpif-sizeof.h:xxxx:xx`.

Comment: OK, what kind of MPI library do you use? Was it compiled for the same compiler version?

Comment: @VladimirF I tried adding mpif90 -std=f2008 ...... as well. But I get the same error.

Comment: A guess (can't tell with no code): Try using the MPI module instead of including the include file, does that fix the problem.

Comment: If you have a non-compliant include file -std=f2008 could result in the compilation failing

Comment: I had downloaded `openmpi 4.0.5-1`

Comment: @NaseefUmmer Source or binary? How did you compiled if source? Which exact release if binary?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and I had downloaded these packages using cygwin.
`gcc-fortran ver 7.4.0` and `openmpi ver 4.0.5`

Comment: Where **exactly** did you download OpenMPI? Are you sure it was compiled for your compiler?

Comment: @VladimirF I have multiple source files as you will see in the `makelist` file I mentioned in the question. In the makelist file, I have specified the compiler as mpif90, which actually runs gcc-fortran 7.4.0

Comment: @VladimirF I have attached the `cygwin` installation manager. I have to just specify what all packages I require in that.

Comment: I am not sure if openmpi 4.0.5 is compatible with gcc-fortran 7.4.0

Comment: You will need gfortran 8 at least to support more than 7 ranks.

Comment: @francescalus  I tried adding mpif90 -std=f2008 ...... as well. But I get the same error.

Comment: If you are using gfortran 7 then there is no compiler option which allows you to compile the Fortran 2008 program `real x(:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:); end`.  You should look for a version of Open MPI which is compatible with gfortran 7 or use a version of gfortran compatible with the Open MPI build you have.

Comment: will adding `gfortran -std=f2008 ...` not make it compile it with f2008?

Comment: gfortran 7 is not a complete Fortran 2008 compiler.  The option `std=f2008` controls only whether compiler extensions or features introduced in later revisions result in an error if used. It doesn't make the compiler support that language revision which it wouldn't otherwise. (Currently indeed, no release of gfortran is a complete Fortran 2008 compiler.)

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the clarification. I am trying to figure out how to install it using cygwin in Win 10. There are only version from 7 to 10. I can't find 2008 in it!

Comment: 2008 is the version of the Fortan standard, not of the gfortran compiler. Just install version 10, the latest. Be sure to get the OpenMPI version, that is compatible with that gfortran version. When you use modules it DOES matter.

Comment: @VladimirF @francescalus `Fatal Error: Cannot read module file ‘precision_types.mod’ opened at (1), because it was created by a different version of GNU Fortran`. I am getting this error when I am using gcc-fortran 10.2.0 and open mpi 3.1.5. Bu the previous error went away!

When I tried `> zcat precision_types.mod`, I am getting that it was compiled using `GFORTRAN module version '14' created from Module.F90`

Comment: @NaseefUmmer Thats what I said *"Be sure to get the OpenMPI version, that is compatible with that gfortran version. When you use modules it DOES matter."*  Or the gfortran version compatible wit that OpenMPI. Try version 8 instead.

Comment: @VladimirF Since the error went away with gcc-fortran 10.20 and openmpi 3.1.5, do I need to change to version 8 now? In cygwin there is only 7.4.0, 9.3.0 and 10.2.0 version available.

Comment: So try version 9.

Comment: @VladimirF I am getting the same error as: `Fatal Error: Cannot read module file ‘precision_types.mod’ opened at (1), because it was created by a different version of GNU Fortran`

Comment: In version 9? Did you try it so quickly?

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, I had just tried it before you wrote the comment just to see if that error would go away :-)

Comment: OK, but where does the precision types module come from? Does it come from somwhere in your code? Try to locate it.

Comment: @VladimirF This is a file (`precision_type.mod`) that has been already compiled using gfortran version 14. I don't have the source file for it re-compile it again using my existing version i.e. 10.2.0

Comment: There is no gfortran 14. Maybe Intel Fortran 14? Where does the file come from? You do need the source and you do need to recompile it. Otherwise it cannot work.

Comment: When I write the command: `$zcat precision_types.mod`, I get the following output: `$ GFORTRAN module version '14' created from Module.F90
`

Comment: OK, that is module version, not gfortran version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681248/is-it-possible-to-determine-which-fortran-compiler-generated-a-mod-file It was generated by gfortran 5 and only gfortran 5 can read it. **You do need the source and you do need to recompile it.** Otherwise it cannot work.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. But I think as for this question, the compatibility between gfortran and openmpi was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we resolved in the comments you need to use the compiler compatible with OpenMPI you are using or the other way use the compiler compatible with your OpenMPI. Not only the header `mpif.h` headers of your MPI contain declarations of arrays with too many ranks for gfortran 7, but once you would use more modern Fortran features you would also hit the incompatibility of the array descriptors and hence the incompatibility of module files.

That incompatibility will become even apparent when you try to use the more modern features like `use mpi` or `use mpi_f08` instead of `include "mpif.h"`. The module files from the MPI library will be immediately rejected by the compiler if they come from an incompatible version. The MPI library must be compiled for the exact main compiler version. That also means that modernizing your application will not fix your current problem.

There is also a module file `.mod.` in your project, that uses module version 14 and was made by gfortran 5. This file will be incompatible with any other gfortran version. You will need to have it recompiled. If you ave the source code, just delete all `.mod` files in your project. If you do not have the source files, you need to get it.

Comment: @VladmirF, thanks for the help! I later found out in Ubuntu kernel in Windows 10, it worked with gfortran-5 (v5.5.0) and mpi (v2.1.1). There are still some glitches towards the end but I think that is a different problem.

Comment: I faced with error with tau installation with fortran. Using gfortran-8 cases the error. However, using gcc-5 with gfortran-5  solves the problem with me.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR you have to use the **same** Fortran compiler (vendor **and** version) that was used to build Open MPI.

Your app does `include 'mpif.h'`, and this internally `include 'mpif-sizeof.h'`.
What happens here is Open MPI was built with a Fortran compiler that supports arrays with more than 7 dimensions, but the Fortran compiler you are using to build your app does not, and hence the error.

That being said, the right fix is to modernize your application, and replace the "legacy" `include 'mpif.h'` with a modern `use mpi`, or even better, `use mpi_f08`.